# escaping malformed URI reference

Tags: html, webpack, atom-editor, ejs

I followed a youtube tutorial on webpack and got a linter error in my HTML stating:

```
escaping malformed URI reference
```

for this image tag:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src=<%=require('./images/tech-town-showcase-students.JPG') %> alt="students meeting with tech business owner"/>
```

What does "escaping" mean here?  The code still seems to run just fine. What do I need to do differently to avoid the linter error?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ASP embedded code in double quotations like this:

```
src="<%=require('./images/tech-town-showcase-students.JPG') %>"
```

Leaving them out causes me headaches to no end. It rarely breaks anything, but the html validators act as though you've tried to escape the tag you're embedding ASP in early by omitting the quotes. At least, in my experience.

Comment: Wrapping in quotes did not remove the linter warning for me.  The missing quotes are glaringly obvious to me now that I have a few more months of experience, though.